# ServiceStack 5 with .NET Core 3.0 doesnt seem to work

Tags: .net-core, servicestack

Not sure if anyone else had this problem.

I have a very simple ServiceStack service

```
public VersionResponse Get(VersionRequest request)
{
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
   return new VersionResponse() { Version = fvi.FileVersion };
}
```

which is registered in servicestack like this

```
appHost.Routes.Add<VersionRequest> ("/api/version");
appHost.RegisterService<CoreService>();
```

This has been working for ever now but after upgrading to .NET Core 3.0 and changing to using Host Builder per Microsoft's instructions it throws an exception when ServiceStack tries to serialize the response to JSON or something else.

This is the error we get on the backend (apologies for the image but I think its obvious that something is wrong within the ServiceStack + .NET Core 3.0 integration)

```
fail: ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal[0]
      Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.WriteDeflaterOutput()
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.WriteCore(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionBody.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush()
   at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream(Object value, Type type, Stream stream) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\JsonSerializer.cs:line 181
   at ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToStream[T](T value, Stream stream) in C:\BuildAgent\work\912418dcce86a188\src\ServiceStack.Text\JsonSerializer.cs:line 174
   at ServiceStack.Serialization.JsonDataContractSerializer.SerializeToStream[T](T obj, Stream stream) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack.Client\Serialization\JsonDataContractSerializer.cs:line 64
   at ServiceStack.Host.ContentTypes.<>c.<.ctor>b__36_0(IRequest r, Object o, Stream s) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ContentTypes.cs:line 20
   at ServiceStack.Host.ContentTypes.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<GetStreamSerializerAsync>b__0(IRequest httpReq, Object dto, Stream stream) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ContentTypes.cs:line 273
   at ServiceStack.HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.WriteToResponse(IResponse response, Object result, StreamSerializerDelegateAsync defaultAction, IRequest request, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix, CancellationToken token) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\HttpResponseExtensionsInternal.cs:line 323
```

Anyone with this problem?

Comment: Post the exception as text, not as an image. The actual exception name, the messages and the method where this happened can be googled to find similar problems. Images can't be googled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack added compatibility with .NET Core 3 in [v5.7](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.7). The [first major fix](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.7#sync-writes-disabled-by-default) seems to be related :

> **Sync writes disabled by default**
>
> The primary issue in supporting .NET Core 3 was accommodating its decision to disable sync Stream writes by default, in-effect disallowing most .NET Serializers from being able to write directly to the Response OutputStream. To work around this, in .NET Core 3 all sync serializers are first written to a pooled MemoryStream before being asynchronously written to the Response’s Output Stream.
>
> Essentially all Content Type Serializers (i.e. Serialization Formats) used in ServiceStack other than HTML View Engines (Razor/Markdown/JSON Report) and #Script Pages (written from ground-up to support async writes) are currently buffered in .NET Core 3. (we’ll look into extending native async serialization support to our own serializers in a future release).
>
> .NET Core 3 does allow you to turn off this restriction on a per-request basis which can be controlled by turning off buffering of sync serializers with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    BufferSyncSerializers = false,
})
```

> Which restores the existing behavior to .NET Core 3 of serializing directly to the Output Stream and marking the request with AllowSynchronousIO=true.

That's what the exception talks about too:

```
Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or 
set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
```